# ncurses: window color don't work

Tags: c, unix, command-line, colors, ncurses

I found the  solution myself: refresh `win` after `stdscr`.

---

I would like to have a white window in a blue screen, and I tried it with the following code:

```
initscr();
WINDOW *win = newwin(10, 10, 10, 10);

start_color();
init_pair(1, COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_BLUE);
init_pair(2, COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_WHITE);

wbkgd(stdscr, COLOR_PAIR(1));
wbkgd(win, COLOR_PAIR(2));
wrefresh(win);
refresh();
```

But I only get a completly blue screen. What is wrong?

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution: Refresh the window after `stdscr`:

```
refresh();
wrefresh(win);
```

instead of:

```
wrefresh(win);
refresh();
```